# Enabling the HyperV Option in windows 8.1 Operating system

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

I am new to windows phone app development from asp.net web,web service,WCF and WebAPI development background knowledge. I installed windows 8.1 and vs2012 express and I installed windows phone SDK as well.

I am using Lenova Z580 model laptop and i have enabled the Intel Virtual Technology from the BIOS settings. Now I am able to see the Hyper V as enabled from the system information screen.

But I am not able to see the Hyper V option from my windows features.

What could be the problem? and what might be the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you looking?

Comment: I am looking in Control Panel-> Programs and Features->Turn Windows Features On or Off

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V is only included in Windows 8.1 **Pro**.

Comment: Ok, is there any other option for me to work with windows phone app development.